# Origin of the saying 'It's a soda'?

Tags: etymology, prepositions, popular-refrains, australian-english

We say that something is easy (in Australia at least) by saying that 'it's a soda?' What is the origin of this please? Why soda?

Comment: I added the `australian-english` tag to this since it's something I've never heard before and I suspect it might be regional. Although it's interesting that it's food related. The expression *I'm* used to is *it's a piece of cake*.

Comment: Could it be related to the fact soda is a _soft_ drink?

Comment: I'm Australian and have never heard that expression before. OP - is it specific to certain states?

Answer (score 1):

According to GDoS it may derive from the card game [Faro:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faro_(card_game))

[Soda:](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/w6oor3q)

> ***1941 Baker Popular Dictionary of Australian Slang 69:***
>
> (of a person) one who is an easy or suitable subject for exploitation. (2) Something easily done.

Comment: So why is the first card discarded from a deck called "soda"? What did/does "soda" mean there?

Comment: I've just looked at Green's Dictionary, you missed an essential element.